# How do i create my own php 5.3.3 package/ppa?

Tags: php, packaging, ppa, launchpad, motu

I really would like to create a package for php 5.3.3 and then make a ppa for it (I would like the php-fpm support but inside the newest release), however this question goes further than this.

I would like to be hand walked through the whole process of compiling and packaging for ubuntu as I do have an intrest in the whole MOTU project but I feel a little bit out of my depth at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding creating your own packages, you might want to take a look at the [PackagingGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/). A good start is probably the [Hands-On session](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/HandsOn). See also the Launchpad PPA documentation [Building a source package](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage) and [Uploading a package to a PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading).

In your case, the easiest/best thing to do is to base your package of the current Ubuntu PHP source package.

A complete walk through might be none trivial. How about if you start experimenting some, and then ask more specific questions?

If you are interested in MOTO work you might also want to consider joining the mailing list [ubuntu-motu](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-motu) as well as the IRC channel #ubuntu-motu (freenode).

Answer (score 2):

There is [dotdeb.org](http://www.dotdeb.org/), which provides recent packages for the LAMP stack, including PHP.

See the [list of PHP-tagged updates](http://www.dotdeb.org/tag/php/).

It is targeted at Debian and not officially supported for Ubuntu, but works quite flawlessly on my Ubuntu boxes.